# Is the downloading of plots from the Stack Overflow Trends not working?

Tags: bug, trends

The link to download the plots from the [Stack Overflow Trends](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends) doesn't work for me.
[image]

Looking at the browser console after clicking on the bottom **Download SVG**, I got the message:

```javascript
Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL: 
data:image/svg+xml;base64,%0ACiAgICAgICAgICAgIDxzdmcgaWQ9InRyZW5kLWNoYXJ0IiB3aWR0aD0iNjYwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjQwMCIgdGl0bGU9IlN0YWNrIE92ZXJmbG93IFRyZW5kcyBDaGFydCIgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4xIiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciPjxnPjwvZz48ZyBjbGFzcz0iY2hhcnQtYXJlYSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJ0cmFuc2xhdGUoMTAwLCAyMCkiPjxnIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0idHJhbnNsYXRlKDAsMzAwKSIgZmlsbD0ibm9uZSIgZm9udC1zaXplPSIxMCIgZm9udC1mYW1pbHk9InNhbnMtc2VyaWYiIHRleHQtYW5jaG9yPSJtaWRkbGUiPjxwYXRoIGNsYXNzPSJkb21haW4iIHN0cm9rZT0iIzAwMCIgZD0iTTAuNSw2VjAuNUg0MT...10aXRsZSIgc3R5bGU9ImZvbnQtd2VpZ2h0OiBib2xkOyI+VGFnPC90ZXh0PjxnIGNsYXNzPSJsZWdlbmQtaXRlbXMiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0idHJhbnNsYXRlKDAsMjApIj48dGV4dCB5PSIwZW0iIHg9IjFlbSI+d2luZG93czwvdGV4dD48dGV4dCB5PSIxZW0iIHg9IjFlbSI+bGludXg8L3RleHQ+PGNpcmNsZSBjeT0iLTAuMjVlbSIgY3g9IjAiIHI9IjAuNGVtIiBzdHlsZT0iZmlsbDogcmdiKDMxLCAxMTksIDE4MCk7Ij48L2NpcmNsZT48Y2lyY2xlIGN5PSIwLjc1ZW0iIGN4PSIwIiByPSIwLjRlbSIgc3R5bGU9ImZpbGw6IHJnYigyNTUsIDEyNywgMTQpOyI+PC9jaXJjbGU+PC9nPjxyZWN0IGNsYXNzPSJsZWdlbmQtYm94Ij48L3JlY3Q+PC9nPjwvc3ZnPgogICAgICAgIA==
```

I experienced that on browsers Firefox v115.0.2, Chrome v114.0.5735.198, and Safari v16.5.2.

Comment: It seems due to [the removal of top-frame navigations to data URLs](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/blink-dev/c/GbVcuwg_QjM?pli=1). Looks like you have to right-click it and use "save link as" to download it now.

Comment: Wow, I got it! Now I managed that.